# Why does it take only one user, not five, to mark a question as a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I just saw this now:

[image]

Apparently, one *user* made a binding decision to close the question. And no, this is not the case in which the user was a moderator at the time, but currently is not (because of how long ago the question was closed).

Comment: Either I didn't see that question, or it wasn't properly announced (under a cryptic title). I didn't see it in the suggested questions when asking this question.

Comment: +1 despite being a dupe. I didn't know this either...

Comment: No disrespect to the gold badge holders, but I think an additional concurring vote should be required. Stack Overflow is consensus based, and allowing a single person to close subverts the principal. Plus, its a check in case of an accidental (or begrudged) action.

Comment: @jww: it is assumed (1) high rep users do not hold grudges, or can suppress these enough to function rationallly, and (2) they got that high rep by being a field expert and so can be expected to tell at a single glance if a post is unclear / too broad / off topic / a duplicate. Not too unreasonable assumptions.  Also, even when *five* people concur on closing, there are options to re-open if deemed unreasonably closed.

Comment: Oh the irony...

Comment: @AstroCB What do you mean?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi A question asking about duplicates was closed as a duplicate.